# matlab remove for loop in matrix computation

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, vectorization

I'm working on a problem on Matlab according to Matrix. I think my code could be improved by remove the for loop. But I really don't know how to fix this one. Can anyone help me, please?
the code is:

```
K = 3;
X = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8];
idx = [1;2;3;1];
for i = 1:K
    ids = (idx == i);
    centroids(i,:) = sum(bsxfun(@times, X, ids))./ sum(ids);
end
```

in this code, data points X is 4x2. There are K=3 centroids, so the centroids is a matrix of 3x2. This code is part of a K-mean function, which is using data points and their closest centroids to find new position of centroids. 
I want to make the code as something without the FOR loop, maybe beginning like this:

```
ids = bsxfun(@eq, idx, 1:K);
centroids = ..............
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the `bsxfun` by using logical indexing, this seems to be a worthwhile performance increase, at least for small matrices `X`. It is best for small `K`, and for a small number of rows of `X`.

```
K = 3;
X = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8];
idx = [1;2;3;1];
centroids=zeros(K,2);
for i = 1:K
    ids = (idx == i);
    centroids(i,:) = sum(X(ids,:),1)./sum(ids);
end
```

If `X` has a large number of rows, this method is fastest:

```
K = 3;
X = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8];
idx = [1;2;3;1];
centroids=zeros(K,2);
t=bsxfun(@eq,idx,1:K);
centroids=bsxfun(@rdivide,t.'*X,sum(t).');
```

And if `K` is very large, Luis' `accumarray` method is fastest.

Comment: Well seen. No need for `bsxfun` here

Comment: Nice solution. Don't forget to preallocate `centroids`

Comment: @Daniel of course! I added a `bsxfun` solution that is faster for large `X` matrices.

Comment: nice one. I tried your code and it works great. Thank you. However, I don't understand this in the first solution: X(ids,:). ids is a vector here. When I tried X([1;0;0;1],:) (the vector is ids in the first loop), error happened. Can you tell me a little about this? Or is there any reference for me to learn this? Thank you!

Comment: OK, when I do `X(ids,:)` basically I'm saying take the rows of `X` where `idx==i` evaluates to `true`, and take all the columns of those rows, that's the `:`. The reason that you got an error doing `X([1;0;0;1],:)` is that the vector `[1;0;0;1]` has to contain logical values, but `[1;0;0;1]` is a numeric vector. If you convert it to a logical vector first, it should work just fine: `X(logical([1;0;0;1]),:)`.

Comment: Pretty smart approach with the matrix multiplication!

Answer (score 4):

You could apply [`accumarray`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). Note that `accumarray` only works when `X` is a column. So, if `X` has **two columns**, you can call `accumarray` twice:

```
centroids(:,1) = accumarray(idx, X(:,1), [], @mean)
centroids(:,2) = accumarray(idx, X(:,2), [], @mean)
```

Alternatively, if `X` contains two columns of **real numbers**, you can use [`complex`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/complex.html) to "pack" the two columns into one complex column, and then unpack the results:

```
centroids = accumarray(idx, complex(X(:,1),X(:,2)), [], @mean);
centroids = [ real(centroids) imag(centroids)];
```

If `X` has an **arbitrary number of columns**, possibly with **complex numbers**, you can loop over columns:

```
centroids = NaN(K, size(X,2)); %// preallocate
for col = 1:size(X,2);
    centroids(:,col) = accumarray(idx, X(:,col), [], @mean);
end
```

Comment: @David That makes sense, because it replaces a loop-over-indices by a loop-over-columns. Did you do some becnhmarking tests?

Comment: I did a couple of rough ones only, but your explanation makes sense.

Comment: If you actually look at the `kmeans` source in MATLAB, this is more or less exactly what they're doing. +1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both your answer and David's are awesome. I really want to honor both. (As his score is 5k while yours is 37.8k, I picked his.) Thank you very much. Really learnt a lot from your code.